# Linking together dlls built with different gcc, error : file not recognized: File format not recognized

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, compilation

I am trying to build with GCC 4.6.1 a project in C++0x that links with a C++17 dll generated with GCC 11.2.0.
I am using Netbeans IDE 7.4 (I think it doesn't matter).

So, the compiling (with GCC 4.6.1) output is the following:
`libdriver17.dll: file not recognized: File format not recognized`. `libdriver17.dll` is indeed my dll generated with GCC 11.2.0.

My driver `driver17.h`:

```
#ifndef DRIVER_H
#define DRIVER_H

#include <stdarg.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
    const char* __stdcall init_driver(void);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif /* DRIVER_H */
```

`driver17.cpp`:

```
#include <string>
#include "driver17.h"

std::string my_str;

const char* init_driver(){
    int x = 45;
    my_str = std::to_string(x);
    return my_str.c_str();
}
```

`main_cpp0x.cpp`:

```
#include "../dependencies/driver17.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::cout<<init_driver()<<std::endl;
}
```

my c++0x `Makefile`:

```
g++ -std=c++0x main_cpp0x.cpp -o test -I../dependencies -L../dependencies -ldriver17
```

`dependencies` is indeed where my dependencies are... (`driver17.h` and `libdriver17.dll`).

I think it is possible to link together different gcc built dlls but I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

I am using Windows btw.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was compiling `driver17` in 64bits, and `main_cpp0x.cpp` in 32bits.